# Recovering toolbar from disconnected window?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-addin, gui

I've faced this problem many times. I created a python addin toolbar and installed it in ArcGIS 10.2 . I work on dual monitors in the office. If accidentally this toolbox is left on the secondary screen and I open my laptop again and disconnect the second screen, I can't see the toolbox, it is hidden or remains on second monitor. I can't find a way to move this toolbox into primary screen. Can any body help me with this weird situation ?

Comment: You might be able to delete (or better, rename) your `normal.mxt` file, which stores data about how you have arranged your ArcMap UI, including toolbars, panes, disconnected panes, etc. Then, the next time you start ArcMap, it'll make a new one. The downside is, it will totally reset your UI--you'll have to reenable/disable any toolbars/panes you use frequently. But the upside is, I think it'll fix your lost toolbar/pane issue. You'll have to do some googling to figure out where `normal.mxt` is typically found on your OS for your version of ArcMap.

Comment: FWIW, I posted that ^ as a comment because I hope there is a better, more universal technique to fix this problem, as it is one of those quirky, nagging problems that seems to affect every manner of software with toolbars and panes; for example Photoshop/Gimp, etc.

Comment: You could write an add-in button using ArcObjects to find all the visible toolbars, and then dock the toolbar that is off the screen. Other than writing custom code, though, I don't know of a way to do this that doesn't involve deleting normal.mxt. If an ArcObjects solution is a possibility, let me know. I have custom code that does this.

Comment: i am sorry, i don't have arc-object in my computer.

Comment: I have found that items on missing second screens can sometimes shift to the very edge of the remaining screen - there may just be a slight border on your active monitor that you can grab with the mouse and pull/resize the toolbar into usable view.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @elrobia I think this is all related to your normal.mxt file. Perhaps this guide book on customising your UI will help

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/customizing-the-ui/fundamentals-of-saving-your-customizations.htm

> If you want to make changes that appear every time you open ArcMap, ArcGlobe, or ArcScene, save them in the Normal template. The customizations saved in the normal template by default are listed below.
>
> - Moving a command item on a built-in toolbar or menu from one location    to another
> - Adding or removing a command from a built-in toolbar
> - Built-in toolbar visibility and position Dockable window visibility    and position